# JAVA - Extract and store all queue elements

Tags: java, queue

In my application I have a queue composed of 4 elements, every element is an HashMap

```
BlockingQueue<HashMap<Integer, double[]>> myInput;
```

I am able to extract all 4 components now doing something like:

```
                try {
                        firstElement = myInput.take();
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(DirectionOfArrival.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }

                try {
                        secondElement = myInput.take();
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(DirectionOfArrival.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }

                try {
                        thirdElement = myInput.take();
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(DirectionOfArrival.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }

                try {
                        fourthElement = myInput.take();
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(DirectionOfArrival.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
```

ending up in having:

```
firstElement
secondElement 
thirdElement 
fourthElement
```

I would like to ask you guys how you would perform the above mentioned operation when working with a queue composed not of only 4 elements (where is easy to get *firstElement, secondElement, thirdElement, fourthElement*), but for example with a queue composed of 400 elements (it is important to point out that I would like to obatin even in that scenario something like firstElement, secondElement, ..., 
fourhundredthElement).

Is there a fast and elegant way to do it?

Any help will be higly appreciated

Thank you a lot in advance

Comment: Don't use a queue if you want to pick some elements randomly in your list. If you really want to use your queue you'll have to remove elements from the queue until you reach the needed one and then re-add the removed elements at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Extract the code in a method and assign the retrieved values in a `List` that you pass to the method with the number of required retrieval.
To maintain the operation number of each result (failure as successful) you will have to add something in the `List` even as the operation fails such as `null` :

```
List<HashMap<Integer, double[]>> takenValues = new ArrayList<>();
int nbTimesRequired = 100;
for (int i=0; i<nbTimesRequired; i++) {     
    takeValues(myInput, takenValues);
}
```

And the method :

```
private static void takeValues(BlockingQueue<HashMap<Integer, double[]>> myInput, List<HashMap<Integer, double[]>> takenValues) {
    try {
        HashMap<Integer, double[]> element = myInput.take();
        takenValues.add(element);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
      takenValues.add(null);   
      Logger.getLogger(DirectionOfArrival.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

    }
 }
```

A better approach would be using `Optional` instead of `null` such as :

```
List<Optional<HashMap<Integer, double[]>>> takenValues = new ArrayList<>();
```

The `takeValues()` method could look like :

```
private static void takeValues(BlockingQueue<HashMap<Integer, double[]>> myInput, List<Optional<HashMap<Integer, double[]>>> takenValues) {
    try {
        HashMap<Integer, double[]> element = myInput.take();
        takenValues.add(Optional.of(element));
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        takenValues.add(Optional.empty());
        Logger.getLogger(DirectionOfArrival.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a fast and elegant way to do it?

1. Use a loop.
2. Store extracted elements in a `List` or an array.  Or process them as you extract them.
3. Don't use named variables like `firstElement`, `secondElement` and so forth.   It is the opposite of elegant.  If you need the 400 or so elements to be named (with meaningful names!) then consider using a `HashMap`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to redesign your code such that it has a more abstract processing component for your queue entries. This can easily be done with a consumer of some sort, the example below just uses a simple method.

As your code is already using a blocking queue, it's fairly simple to implement it using a loop:

```
BlockingQueue<HashMap<Integer, double[]>> myInput;

while(true) {
    this.process(myInput.take());
}
```

And the `process` method could look like the one below:

```
private void process(Map<Integer, double[]> queueInput) {
    System.out.println("Messageges:" + queueInput);
    //run meaningful code...
}
```

The above just repeatedly reads messages off the queue and processes them whenever they arrive.